# Can I control any transistor (NPN/PNP) using a GPIO pin of my MCU? Is my schematic correct?

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, stm32, gpio

[image]

Can I control any transistor (NPN/PNP) using a GPIO pin of my MCU? Is my above schematic correct?

---

**EDIT 15/02/24: A REVISED SCHEMATIC, AFTER THE ANSWERS**

Is the revised schematic below now correct? My connection is: MCU_GPIO to Q1_b and Q1_c end with 5 V and there is a trim pot so I can control the intensity of the LED and I want to turn the LED on and off using the MCU.

Read [this](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_4) for some more detailed explanation.

[image]T

Comment: What logic levels are the MCU using?

Comment: Aside from the on-topic transistor comments, if there is a LED with no series resistor connected to J3 you'll likely destroy both the LED and the trimpot the first time you turn it all the way up.

Comment: On your edit and new schematic: I'm afraid it's still wrong, Q1's load is just a resistor going to 5V, which does nothing useful. Draw what I'd put in my answer's schematic. If you want brightness control, is there a reason you can't use the MCU to generate PWM on PB5? Sorry to have to ask but do you have much understanding of circuit design and of the components you're using here? Your circuits show you not understanding at a very basic level.

Comment: @Bala, you'd edited your question 5 hours ago, (a) changing its original schematic which all the answers address so they no longer make sense, looked wrong and invited downvotes by new readers. You also (b) dumped in a new schematic without any explanation. The last question edit notes were added by me, to show you how to do it, which you then didn't. Therefore I have removed those last edits. **Instead, please can you** starting with a comment answering the questions in my comment. You throwing changes at your schematic will not help you learn and progress - and design a board that works.

Comment: Since my above comment, you again put the same changes back again. I have removed them for the same reasons stated above: do not edit your question to remove significant previous information - lots of answers have been written on it. To do so is against site policy.  Further changes will be removed, do not edit war. Please work with the site, not against it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schematic is not correct and will not work.
You have to redesign all the transistor and LED part, at least.

As it is now connected, when the transistor would be on, the VCC (+5V) source would be directly connected to GND. This is a short and this is not good.
You need also a base resistor.

Check this for some more detailed explanation:
https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_4.html

Answer (score 13):

To "is my schematic correct"...

The below circuit is wrong. First, Q1 will try short out the rail when PB5 is driven HIGH. Second, Q1's base is a diode to GND so Q1 will try to clamp PB5 to 0.6..0.8 V when PB5 is driving HIGH and this may well damage Q1 and the MCU.

[image]

Instead, use the following circuit. I imagine you wanted Q1 to switch a load and your schematic describes that load as an LED.

R2 limits the current into the Q1 base when PB5 is driving HIGH. The current will be sufficient to switch Q1 on and sink around 2.9 mA through the LED and R3, assuming a 1.6 V LED drop and Q1 Vce(on) of 0.3 V.

When the MCU is first powered on and/or reset, PB5 and the rest of its GPIO pins will configured as inputs. When inputs, the GPIO will output an 'input pin leakage current' which can be enough to switch on Q1. R1 is a pull down resistor that drains this current to GND and ensures Q1 is off. When the software has configured PB5 as an output and is driving the Q1 base HIGH or LOW, R1 is no longer needed so a high-value resistor is used that will draw little current from the HIGH PB5 voltage. Unless the circuit must be very power-efficient, this R1 current when PB5 is HIGH is negligible.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNWk1xm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is the correct answer. It addresses the problem of Q1's collector, puts R1 in a more appropriate place, and specifies very sensible values for R1, R2 *and* R3. I wish I could +10 this, to put it at the top.

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't control **any** transistor, because there are different kinds of transistors, some may require more current or more voltage than any microcontroller can provide.

Your schematic has no base resistor, it will likely destroy the MCU and/or the transistor with overcurrent.

But even if you put a base resistor, turning the transistor on will make it short 5V to ground so it will anyway burn up.

Comment: so which smd transitor is good for 5v ? i want to make transistor as a switch what to do for that

Comment: @BalajiNadar That is a completely different quesrion. Did you read my answer? The transistor you are using is not a problem. The problem is how you use it. You don't need a better transistor, it is good enough.

Comment: should i add resistor to 5v side wire?